# Rails join without primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a date_dimensions table with dates that has a PK for every day. I also have a reports table with a month_year as the only date. I need to do a join query that joins date_dimensions to reports. **The only use of this relationship in the app will be to run this query.**

How would I set up this relationship? Or can I just write a raw query to join the two?

date_dimensions:

**Model:**

```
class DateDimension < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reports
end
```

**Migration:**

```
class CreateDateDimensions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :date_dimensions do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.integer :month
      t.string :year_month_name
      t.integer :year
    end
  end
end
```

reports:

**Model:**

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :date_dimension
end
```

**Migration:**

```
class CreateReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reports do |t|
      t.string :customer_name
      t.string :month_year
      t.integer :page_views
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can use raw SQL with `joins`; e.g. `Report.joins(" ... ")`. Check the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
DateDimension.joins('INNER JOIN reports ON date_dimensions.year_month_name = reports.month_year')
```

Although your names indicate that they don't have the year and month in the same order so that might not work.

Don't forget to add indexes for both of those join columns.

#### Update 1

Sorry, I missed that you weren't using this elsewhere. You could set up the relationship as:

```
`has_many :reports, primary_key: 'year_month_name', foreign_key: 'month_year'`
```

then you should be able to use standard Rails syntax to access the tables

Comment: I think I will use this solution. So, if I go with this, should I even specify the has_many, belongs_to in the models, and the foreign_key in the migration?

Comment: I see your update 1, You think it's ok that the date_dimensions table has a granularity of date but the PK is year_month_name on the relationship you suggested?

Comment: I can't really say without knowing more about the data. I did make two assumptions (1) The column is called `year_month_name` in `date_dimensions` but `month_year` in `reports`. I assumed that the dates were in the same format, even though the names imply otherwise, but I can't really tell. (2) If you have 2 `DateDimension` records with different dates/ids but the same value for `year_month_name` then it wouldn't actually break anything but the report would be accessible through more than one instance. If this is not acceptable you would have to find another way to limit your join.